# For every rational number, does there exist a sequence of irrationals which converges to it?

Tags: real-analysis

I can think of of examples where a sequence of irrationals converges to $0$. But if we pick any rational will there always exist a sequence of irrationals which converges to it?

I cannot find a straight answer to this question.

Comment: Let $r$ be our rational. Look at $r+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}$. This may be the example you had in mind, "shifted" by $r$.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Assume your number is $\frac{p}{q}$. Then the sequence $$a_n=\frac{\pi}{n}+\frac{p}{q}$$ converges to the given number and is irrational (any irrational number in the place of $\pi$ would do).

Comment: this is assuming $\lim_{n\to\inf}$, right?

Comment: @ColeJohnson Yes, right!

Answer (score 16):

Yes, take a sequence consisting of your sequence of irrationals converging to $0$ plus your desired rational limit.

Answer (score 4):

Yes: If $r\in\Bbb Q$, then $\forall n\in\Bbb N$: ${rn\over n+\sqrt2}\in{\Bbb Q}^c$ and
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{rn\over n+\sqrt2}=r.$$

Answer (score 3):

For any rational number $x=\frac{p}{q}$ with $\gcd(p,q)=1$, just consider:
$$ x_n = \frac{p}{q}\cdot\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}.$$
Clearly any $x_n$ belong to $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ and we have $\lim_{n\to +\infty} x_n = x$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Consider

$\frac{p}{q} - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}$